# Problema con formulario Java para app hibrida

Tags: javascript, formularios, app

Tengo un código en javacript con el cual quiero hacer un app que registre series, el tema es que me da error y no se que puede ser:

Armar formulario Archivo.js

```
$('form').on('sumbit', function () {

    var nombre = $('#name').val();
    var fecha = $('input[type="date"]').val();
    var medio = $('#medio').val();
    var episodios = $('#episodios').val();
    var nuevo_div = $('<div></div>');



    var contenido = "<strong>"Los increibles"</strong><br> <span>" 1 / 7 / 2018 "< /span><br><strong>"Pelicula"</strong> < br > < strong > 01 < /strong> " ;

    nuevo_div.html(contenido);

    var cantidad_divs = $('#grilla > div').length;


    if (cantidad_divs % 2 == 0) {

        nuevo_div.attr("class", "ui-block-a");

    } else {

        nuevo_div.attr("class", "ui-block-b");

    }

    $('#grilla').append(nuevo_div);

    $.mobile.navigate('#series');

    return false;

});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Noteflix</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="jqm/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/estilos.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/tusseries.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!--Presentación -->

   <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="e">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Noteflix</h1>
            <a href="#info"
            data-role="button" 
            data-icon="info" 
            data-iconpos="notext">Alumnos</a>
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Acá vas a poder anotar tus series y películas favoritas, las que estás siguiendo y las quue querés ver, películas que te recomendaron para que no te las olvides o los próximos entrenos para que no se te pase ninguno.</p>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="e" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                <li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a href="#series">NOTAS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h2>DAM - 5to Cuatrimestre - 2018</h2>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--Seccion de series -->


<div data-role="page" id="series" data-theme="e">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Tus series</h1>
           <a href="#home"
            data-role="button" 
            data-icon="home" 
            data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
           <a href="#agregar" 
            data-icon="plus" 
            data-iconpos="notext"
            class="ui-btn-right">Agregar</a>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-grid-a" id="grilla">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
               <strong>Los increibles</strong><br>
               <span>1/7/2018</span><br><strong>Pelicula</strong><br><strong>01</strong>  
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
               <strong>Dragon Ball</strong><br>
                <span>5/7/2018</span><br><span>serie</span><br><span>536</span>  
            </div>









            </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#series" data-icon="alert" class="ui-btn-active">Series</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#peliculas" data-icon="camera">Películas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#estrenos" data-icon="check">Estrenos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>




<div data-role="page" id="peliculas" data-theme="e">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Tus películas</h1>
           <a href="#home"
            data-role="button" 
            data-icon="home" 
            data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-grid-a" id="grilla">

            </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#series" data-icon="alert">Series</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#peliculas" data-icon="camera" class="ui-btn-active">Películas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#estrenos" data-icon="check">Estrenos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>




<div data-role="page" id="estrenos" data-theme="e">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Tus estrenos</h1>
           <a href="#home"
            data-role="button" 
            data-icon="home" 
            data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-grid-a" id="grilla">

            </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#series" data-icon="alert">Series</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="camera">Películas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-active">Estrenos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>




<div data-role="page" id="agregar">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Nuevo Serie/Pelicula/Estreno</h1>
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">

            <form>

                 <input type="text" id="name"  placeholder="Nombre serie,pelicula o serie" required>

                <input type="date" name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" required />

                <select name="donde" id="medio">
                    <option value="Serie">Serie</option>
                    <option value="Película">Película</option>
                    <option value="Estreno">Estreno</option>
                </select>

                <input type="number" id="episodios" placeholder="Episodios" step=".1" required/>

                <a href="#series" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Cancelar</a>
                <input type="submit" 
                       value="Agregar" 
                       data-theme="e" 
                       data-inline="true"/>
            </form>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h2>DAM - 5to Cuatrimestre - 2018</h2>
        </div>
    </div>



<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: java o javascript?

Comment: Hola Matt, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

No queda muy claro lo que quieres conseguir, pero veo que tienes un error en tu código. A la hora de crear el contenido pones comillas y dejas algunos nombres fuera del string.La forma de crear el contenido es esta:

```
var contenido = "<strong>Los increibles</strong><br> <span> 1 / 7 / 2018 < /span><br><strong>Pelicula</strong> < br > < strong > 01 < /strong> " ;
```

Y en caso de quere usar variables tienes que concatenarlos con el "+":

```
var contenido = "<strong>" + titulo +"</strong><br> <span>" + fecha + "< /span><br><strong>" + pelicula + "</strong> < br > < strong > 01 < /strong> " ;
```